# How can I print a list of sets to a file, with python, in a format that is easily put into excel, eliminating all the unwanted characters?

Tags: python, excel, list, printing, set

I have been using

```
for item in dictlist:
    print>>working_outfile, item
```

to print a ***list*** of ***sets*** to a .txt file and opening that with excel, which then allows me to convert the list to a comma delimited file, creating a spreadsheet.

The problem is that when I have this open, I have been going in and manually replacing the first open and close parentheses, all the apostrophes, the "set[", and the close bracket characters in order to clean up the look of the spread sheet.

Any suggestions or pointers on how I can fix this print so that other users of this program don't have to learn how to find and replace all of those characters?

EDIT: It ultimately gives output looking something like this:

> ('aaa' | set(['stuff' | 'eggs' | 'spam']))
>
> ('bbb' | set(['stuff' | 'eggs' | 'spam']))
>
> ('ccc' | set(['stuff' | 'spam']))

where | is the next cell

and I want:

> aaa | stuff | eggs | spam
>
> bbb | stuff | eggs | spam
>
> ccc | stuff | spam

Example of print dictlist would be:

> [('gcagag', set(['FlyingFox mef2d upstream a1', 'Gibbon mef2a upstream
>   a1', 'Elephant mef2d upstream a1', 'Gorilla mef2c upstream a1',
>   'gibbon mef2c upstream a1', 'Monkey mef2d upstream a1', 'Gorilla mef2a
>   upstream a1', 'Rhesus mef2c upstream a1', 'MouseLemur mef2d upstream
>   a1', 'BrownBat mef2d upstream a1', 'Dolphin mef2d upstream a1',
>   'Kung-Fu-Panda! mef2d upstream a1', 'Armadillo mef2d upstream a1',
>   'chimp mef2d upstream a1', 'Chimp mef2a upstream a1', 'Marmoset mef2d
>   upstream a1', 'Rabbit mef2d upstream a1', 'EuroShrew mef2d upstream
>   a1', 'Alpaca mef2d upstream a1', 'chimp mef2c upstream a1',
>   'EuroHedgeHog mef2d upstream a1', 'Dog mef2d upstream a1', 'mouse
>   mef2d upstream a1', 'Gibbon mef2d upstream a1', 'Rat mef2d upstream
>   a1', 'Gorilla mef2d upstream a1', 'Orangutan mef2d upstream a1',
>   'human mef2d upstream a1'])), ('aaataa', set(['mouse mef2c upstream
>   a1', 'Alpaca mef2a upstream a1', 'horse mef2a upstream a1', 'opossum
>   mef2a upstream a1', 'Gibbon mef2a upstream a1', 'MouseLemur mef2a
>   upstream a1', 'elephant mef2a upstream a1', 'GuineaPig mef2a upstream
>   a1', 'Rat mef2d upstream a1', 'Dolphin mef2a upstream a1', 'Gorilla
>   mef2a upstream a1', 'Rhesus mef2c upstream a1', 'mouse mef2a upstream
>   a1', 'dog mef2c upstream a1', 'Human mef2a upstream a1', 'Chimp mef2a
>   upstream a1', 'Orangutan mef2a upstream a1']))]

notice there are 2 items and their associated sets here. the actual dictlist has anywhere from 500-40000 items in it so this is just a small cut

Comment: So each item is a set?  Have you tried just iterating over the sets in an inner for loop and controlling the formatting that way?  Or doing a slice on the `str` or `__repr__` of the set to chop off the offending characters?  Or using a regex to do the same?

Comment: @sr2222 the list is precisely a translated dictionary that has an item (or a key) and an associated set. I suppose that would make it a 2d list? and I have not tried that, but would it not just cut off the apostrophes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a list of tuples, where each tuple consists of a string and a set.  So, to properly use the CSV writer, you need each of those tuples to be "flat":

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'wb'))

for item in mydata:  # mydata is your list of tuples, so item is a tuple
    row = [item[0]] + list(item[1])
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I can't figure out why but the output.csv keeps coming up empty.

only thing I changed is "mydata" to "dictlist" which is my list of tuples

Comment: disregard the above!! my mistake on the data input. Works wonderfully, excellent solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the csv module. http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')
>>> spamWriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Relevant to your code (updated after looking at the output of print dictlist).

```
>>> import csv
>>> spamWriter = csv.writer(open('eggs.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')
>>> for item in dictlist:
        tmp = [item(0)]       
        tmp.extend(item[1])
        spamWriter.writerow(tmp)
```

Comment: I think he would still want a comma delimiter.

Comment: @Amjith my list of sets is called dictlist and I used that (just changing it to spamwriter.writerow(dictlist).

It took and wrote each list item and its associated set to one cell, and still kept all the characters I didn't want

Comment: @user1295913 Edited the code above to show how to use it with your dictlist.

Comment: @Amjith: How would you be closing and or flushing the file?

Comment: @Amjith Better, but it is now giving me "item | set(['1st','2nd']))"
where "|" is a cell division.

I need 1st and 2nd to each show up in a separate row and without the "set([", the apostrophes, or the ])). Is there someway to get the csv writer to do that? or is this an excel issue?

Comment: @Abhijit I'm basically giving pointers and guiding the user towards the answer. Although the file handler should close when the script finishes.

Comment: @Amjith I edited the original post with a better example of what I want FYI

Comment: @user1295913 We need to know the exact structure of dictlist in order to give a better answer. Can you post the output of 'print dictlist' or 'print item'?

Comment: @sr2222: The delimiter is comma by default. (Which makes sense, as the 'C' in 'CSV' stands for "comma".) Normally, you leave out the `delimiter` parameter entirely when writing Excel CSVs.

Comment: @user1295913 I believe that should take care of the specific situation.

Comment: @user1295913 The answer given by John Y below is a lot more succinct. Personally I'd use that one. :)

Comment: @JohnY, yup, and yet in his original version, he had, if memory serves, a space for the delim, not comma or default.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the list of numbers as a CSV you can do the following

```
>>> somelist=[set(random.sample(xrange(1,100),4)) for i in range(1,5)]
>>> out = repr(somelist).translate(None,"([)]").replace("set","")
'8, 98, 91, 10, 27, 3, 85, 37, 64, 33, 11, 69, 32, 83, 85, 38'
```

You can then write the string out to a file.

Alternatively you can also expand the set as a list of numbers or strings if your string might contain the characters that are added as part of the representation

```
>>> somelist=[set(random.sample(xrange(1,100),4)) for i in range(1,5)]
>>> [e for s in somelist for e in s]
[17, 43, 63, 97, 16, 65, 58, 11, 49, 10, 91, 95, 41, 20, 85, 70]
>>>
```

You may also use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module to write the data to a file

From OPs comment as he wanted the sets in different rows, Here is an update

```
>>> fin=open('somecsv.csv', 'wb')
>>> csvwriter = csv.writer(open('somecsv.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',')
>>> for s in somelist:
    csvwriter.writerow(list(s))
>>> fin.close()
```

Comment: The problem with this is that there are thousands of items in the list and tens of thousands more in the sets. So writing just this string is creating one very long line and eliminating the ability of excel to read it as a multi-row spreadsheet

Comment: I'm going to try this out and see what it gives me. I updated the original post with a better example of what I am looking for.